# Date Difference in php on days?

Tags: php, date, datediff

Is there a quick way to calculate date difference in php? For example:

```
$date1 = '2009-11-12 12:09:08';
$date2 = '2009-12-01 08:20:11';
```

And then do a calculation, $date2 minus $date1

I read php.net documentation, but no luck. Is there a quick way to do it?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - that's not an *exact* duplicate, since it's a good deal more complicated (the OP in that question wants date formatted as in "x years, y months, z days" etc).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

strtotime will convert your date string to a unix time stamp. (seconds since the unix epoch.

```
$ts1 = strtotime($date1);
$ts2 = strtotime($date2);

$seconds_diff = $ts2 - $ts1;
```

Comment: please note that this might give you different results if between the 2 dates there is a time change (like in spring or autumn).

try this: 

echo strtotime('2013-03-30 21:00') - strtotime('2013-03-29 21:00');
echo strtotime('2013-03-31 21:00') - strtotime('2013-03-30 21:00');

you get 86400 and 82800.

the results are actually correct. but if you divide by 86400 to get the number of days you need to take that into account (so better use the date diff function).

Comment: If you're on a modern version of php, use adam's solution. PHP has a lot of code to account for anomalies related to time.

Answer (score 209):

I would recommend to use **date->diff** function, as in example below:

```
   $dStart = new DateTime('2012-07-26');
   $dEnd  = new DateTime('2012-08-26');
   $dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
   echo $dDiff->format('%r%a'); // use for point out relation: smaller/greater
```

see http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: This function requires php 5.3 or better as stated by @txyoji

Comment: use `$diffInDays = (int)$dDiff->format("%r%a");` to get values you can directly use such as "-2" or "2" (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php for format parameter descriptions)

Comment: And change "-" to ":" if you accidentaly or not trying to put date with time...

Comment: Why would you put `date()` function as first parameter of DateTime constructor? Function call `date('2012-07-26')` will return `2012-07-26`, so I really see no point of calling that function.

Comment: `<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2016-05-30');
$datetime2 = date_create('2016-05-30');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

echo "difference " . $interval->days . " days ";`

Output:
difference 6015 days

How can we get zero days for same date?

Answer (score 22):

Below code will give the output for number of days, by taking out the difference
between two dates..

```
$str = "Jul 02 2013";
$str = strtotime(date("M d Y ")) - (strtotime($str));
echo floor($str/3600/24);
```

Comment: When trying to calculate date difference for my `JQuery datepicker`, `floor` was giving me strange result. By example, `floor((strtotime(((isset($_POST['date']) and strtotime($_POST['date'])) ? $_POST['date'] : date("Y-m-d"))) - strtotime(date("Y-m-d")))/3600/24))` give me a difference of 9.9583333333333 between March 31st and March 21st (so 9 with rounded down when I'm expecting 10). I used the `round` function to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes Jonathan, 

You are right.

Comment: Hey Bro I have a doubt, can You explain what is the use of 3600/24 in your echo

Comment: @SivaGanesh he's making the timestamp in hours (/3600) and then in days (/24)