# Operations with dates

Tags: cakephp

I need to check if is missing 10 days or less to arrive at a certain date.

I'm trying this:

```
   if(date('d/m/Y') >= CakeTime::format('d/m/Y','30/04/2013','-10 days', true )) {
```

but apparently the Caketime::format is not working correctly.

Any help, pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP doesn't prevent you from using regular PHP functionality. If PHP *itself* already offers what you're looking for, it is even prefered.

In PHP, you can calculate the difference between two dates using [`DateTime::diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

A quick search on StackOverflow gave me this question, which contains proper examples:

[Date Difference in php on days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940338/date-difference-in-php-on-days)