# Days remaining before birthday in php

Tags: php, date

I have 2 variables in a PHP script:

```
$birthday = "1977-10-03";

$now = time();
```

How do I calculate days remaining before the birthday (`$daysRemaining = ?`)

Comment: Please ONLY post a question on StackOverflow after you have done your research. Please edit your question to include attempts that have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate [Date Difference in php on days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940338/date-difference-in-php-on-days?rq=1)

**EDITED:**

```
$diff=$date-time();//time returns current time in seconds
$days=floor($diff/(60*60*24));//seconds/minute*minutes/hour*hours/day)
$hours=round(($diff-$days*60*60*24)/(60*60));
```

Is this how you wanted?

```
$birthday = "1977-9-10";
$cur_day = date('Y-m-d');
$cur_time_arr = explode('-',$cur_day);
$birthday_arr = explode('-',$birthday);

$cur_year_b_day = $cur_time_arr[0]."-".$birthday_arr[1]."-".$birthday_arr[2];

if(strtotime($cur_year_b_day) < time())
{
    echo "Birthday already passed this year";
}
else
{
    $diff=strtotime($cur_year_b_day)-time();//time returns current time in seconds
    echo $days=floor($diff/(60*60*24));
}
```

Comment: Hi, this does not seems to work, it gives me a big number. i want the remaining days in the current year

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$birthday = strtotime("1977-10-03");
$now = time();
$datediff = $now - $birthday;
$daysRemaining = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
echo $daysRemaining;
```

Comment: Hi, this does not seems to work, it gives me a big number. i want the remaining days in the current year tks