# Days remaining before birthday - laravel - carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Is there any easiest way to calculate remaining ***days*** to birthady?

there is a similar question:

[Days remaining before birthday in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616622/days-remaining-before-birthday-in-php)

but I want to use `Carbon` library.

like: `1989-6-30`

---

**update**

```
    function getDifferenceTwoDate($date)
    {
        $birthday = Carbon::parse($date);

        $birthday->year(date('Y'));
        return Carbon::now()->diffInDays($birthday, false);
    }

getDifferenceTwoDate('1989-6-30')
```

but it returns `0`

and

```
getDifferenceTwoDate('1991-5-22')
```

but it return `-38`

Comment: Have you tried the `diffInDays` function Carbon provides?

Comment: yes, but it returns a big days: `        $startTime = Carbon::parse(date('Y-m-d'));
        $finishTime = Carbon::parse($date);

        return $finishTime->diffInDays($startTime);`

Comment: Ah, I see. You'll have to do a bit more manual logic there, then. Take the birth date, do `->year(date('Y'))` to set the year to this year (with a bit of logic to set it to *next* year if they've already had their birthday this year), *then* do the difference in days.

Comment: @ceejayoz updated question.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, you need logic to add a year if the birthday has already passed this year.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming $birthday is a Carbon instance, you can reset the year to this year with:

```
$birthday->year(date('Y'));
```

Then you can get a difference in days from now.  The second argument as false ensures past dates will return negative and future days will return positive.

```
Carbon::now()->diffInDays($birthday, false);
```

So if you get `-30` you'd need to calculate based on next year, if you get 30, you'd have 30 days until their birthday.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian, like I said, you'd need to calculate based on the next year if it returns negative.