# Calculate number of days between two dates with accuracy

Tags: php, date

Well, this may be a stone age question, but I got confused after reading so many questions here.

1. A simple solution using `strtotime()` has been pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940338/date-difference-in-php-on-days?lq=1), but the last comment about time change for the accepted answer leads me to diff function.
2. Many of the links suggest me to diff function , something like [Calculate number of hours between 2 dates in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108591/calculate-number-of-hours-between-2-dates-in-php/3108800#3108800).

   - But then I saw a PHP bug that diff shows wrong values when first date of the days are involved ([link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65003&edit=3)).
   - Also days part on diff function always return 6015 on Windows platform ([link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51184)).

I read many more links and all of them ends with diff() function. Is there a reliable solution for this problem?

Note: I am using PHP version 5.3.5

Comment: There's a bug in your version of PHP that will make working with dates difficult. You need to upgrade your version of PHP. Once you do this becomes trivial to do.

Comment: @John The "bug" exists in *all* versions of PHP: http://3v4l.org/LHjKM

Comment: I was actually referring to a different one that was patched in 5.3.6. (Pretty sure its the first one [in this list under DateTime](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.6))

Comment: Ah, the other one. My bad. :)

Comment: Looks like you've done a fair bit of research. Not sure why this is so heavily downvoted (other than the general Meta view that the PHP tag is going to hell in a handcart) so +1.

Comment: Guys! Downvoting should be only when there is not enough research, Do I have to paste all the links for the question which I have researched

Comment: @John Conde: You mean there is no solution for this in 5.3.5.

Comment: Amal Murali: Thanks for the editing.

Comment: @halfer I agree with you

Comment: Is there any solution without upgrading :(

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use datediff neither strtotime, one more solution is to use `getTimestamp` and calc the difference

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('13-03-01');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('13-04-01');

$datetime1TS = datetime1->getTimestamp;
$datetime2TS = datetime2->getTimestamp;

$interval = ($datetime2TS - $datetime1TS)/(60*60*24);
```

But i think that datediff is better.

Comment: But it will be same as strtotime, compare it with the link I provide in the first both will be same.