# How to subtract two dates in php

Tags: php, yii

I want to subtract the `datenow` and the `registerdate` and use the result in a condition.

Following is the code:

```
    public function actionCheckDate(){
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'); 
        $datenow = date('Y-m-d');   

        $id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
        $models = GamesDevelopers::model()->find('id='.$id); 
        $registerdate = CHtml::encode($models->registerdate);           
        $active = strtotime($datenow)-strtotime($registerdate);

        print_r($active);
        die();
}
```

The result is : **627173** , how I gonna to know that **627173** is how many time or date ?

**UPDATED**

```
    public function actionCheckDate(){
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur'); 
        $datenow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

        $id = Yii::app()->user->getState('id');
        $models = GamesDevelopers::model()->find('id='.$id); 
        $registerdate = CHtml::encode($models->registerdate);           

        $diff = abs(strtotime($registerdate) - strtotime($datenow));

        $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
        $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
        $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

        printf("%d years, %d months, %d days\n", $years, $months, $days);
        die();
}
```

**Worked fine but how to count hours ?**

To find hours:

```
    $hours = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24)*24);

    printf("%d hours\n",$hours);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp difference is in seconds. You can convert this into minutes(divide by 60), hours (divide by 60*60), day (divide by 24*60*60) & so on.

There are lots of examples & tutorials given on the web, please refer:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_diff.asp

[How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

[Date Difference in php on days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940338/date-difference-in-php-on-days)

Comment: the second link u given is good ... but it only count until days ... how about hour ??

Comment: i success to hours ... thanks you anyway ... =)

Answer (score 2):

use this ...

```
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
```

Comment: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given

Answer (score 0):

Divide by `60` will give you `Minutes`.
Divide by `60*60` will give you `Hours`.
Divide by `60*60*24` will give you `Days`.
and so on.

```
<your timestamp> / 60*60 = hours
```