# How to calculate days between 2 month?

Tags: php, date

I want to calculate days between 2 month.1 date is set that is 01-03-2014 and second date will be given by user.This may be any date for example 14-05-2014.Now i want to calculate days between these 2 dates?
Thanks

Comment: See [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

Comment: One day at a time....

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  Or are you just asking for so called "homework" help?  Because SO users generally only help with the former, not the later.

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940338/date-difference-in-php-on-days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime` for this, and do a simply calculation. See [**DateTime:diff**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
<?php

$start= new DateTime('14-05-2014');
$end= new DateTime('01-03-2014');
$interval = $start->diff($end);

echo $interval->format("%a total days"); //Output: 74 total days
```

https://eval.in/236630