# PHP days calulation between two dates including leap year day

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to calculate the days between two dates but if I select dates between before 29 Feb or after 29 its coming ok but if I select date between before 29 and after 29 then its giving me wrong days. Here is my code please check how can I fix it ?

```
$daylen = 60*60*24;
$date1 = '2016-01-01';
$date2 = '2016-03-31';
$numberDays =(strtotime($date2)-strtotime($date1))/$daylen;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dStart = new DateTime('2012-07-26');
$dEnd  = new DateTime('2012-08-26');
$dDiff = $dStart->diff($dEnd);
echo $dDiff->format('%R'); // use for point out relation: smaller/greater
echo $dDiff->days;
```

[Date Difference in php on days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940338/date-difference-in-php-on-days)
[DUBLICATE]

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php